# Determine whether user is likely to be typing in dd/mm or mm/dd

Tags: javascript, date, locale, country

I have an input date field on a webpage which allows the users to type in a date in various common acceptable formats.

The user can however enter a date like 10/11/12. This could mean 10 November 2012 or 11 October 2012. Is there a way to determine which of thes etwo they are likely entering without prompting them each time depending on their locale etc. I looked at using javascript toLocaleDateString but the output formats vary greatly between different browsers.

Would there be another way to determine this information ? I would maybe need to determine if they are based in the US or not.

Comment: Of course not, either are perfectly valid dates. You could use IP info to determine their continent, but meh.

Comment: I think people generally use `-` or `.` to specify dd-mm-yy format dates. See [note on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: You can MAKE sure that it comes in the right way by using a datepicker

Comment: Probably best to just tell them what format they should use.

Comment: Even doing IP lookup won't work. I use the American way, despite not currently living in the U.S.